# Does Babel.js support ES6 Object.observer() method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Couldn't find any information about this on the official [site](https://babeljs.io/). As I understood, this method doesn't support for this moment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Babel does not cover `Object.observe`, and it will not in the future either. `Object.observe` isn't part of ES6 and has been dropped from the proposal process in general. If you need programmatic access to property processing on an object, you would want to use an ES6 `Proxy` object with handlers to implement the behavior you are looking for.

Babel also does not implement `Proxy` since it is requires engine-level functionality that cannot be polyfilled.